# When deciding how to scale features, do the types of activation function matter?

Tags: neural-networks, feature-engineering

Typically there are two types of feature scaling methods:
Z-score scaling (standardization) and Min-max scaling (normalization). Standardization normalizes each column towards a mean of zero and
standardization of ones. Min-max scaling ensures all the values are between 0 and 1.

I was told that, **when choosing the feature scaling method from the two, the distribution of each feature matters.**

> "The scaling using mean and standard deviation assumes that the data
>   are normally distributed, that is, most of the data are sufficiently
>   close to the mean" "[Guassian scaling will be helpful if your data are
>   roughly normally distributed. Otherwise, some other kind of scaling
>   might give better results](https://www.quora.com/Which-advantages-does-MinMax-scaling-have-over-a-standard-scaling-using-the-mean-and-the-standard-deviation)."

However today I am reading this [book about Deep Learning](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=zZlUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=Min-max%20scaling:%20This%20ensures%20all%20the%20values%20are%20between%200%20and%201,%20that%20is,%20positive.%20This%20is%20the%20default%20approach%20if%20we%20are%20using%20sigmoid%20as%20our%20output%20activation.&source=bl&ots=rjARC5km5V&sig=ACfU3U3dqH4_w0RMVfE2O-Af3Uvv1pGXKg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVj8TFrJrgAhUPXn0KHaKBBBMQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Min-max%20scaling%3A%20This%20ensures%20all%20the%20values%20are%20between%200%20and%201%2C%20that%20is%2C%20positive.%20This%20is%20the%20default%20approach%20if%20we%20are%20using%20sigmoid%20as%20our%20output%20activation.&f=false), and it mentioned:

> This (Z-score) is particularly suitable for **activation functions such
>   as tanh** that output values on both sides of zero.
>   Min-max scaling:
>   This ensures all the values are between 0 and 1, that is, positive.
>   This is the default approach if we are using **sigmoid** as our output
>   activation.

How so? **How are the choice of feature scaling related to the activation functions?**

It seems to me that both Sigmoid and Tanh function have maximum gradient when the input is around 0. Is it about the output instead of the input?

[image]